# Permute numbers using permute str logic

Tags: python, subset, permutation, backtracking

As a part of trying to get better with backtracking I wrote the following code to permute a string:

```
def permute(str):
    permuteHelper(str,"")

def permuteHelper(str,chosen):
    if not str:
        print(chosen)
    else:
        for i in range(len(str)):
        #choose
            currChar = str[i] #The char we choose
            chosen += currChar #Add chosen char to chosen chars
            str = str[0 : i] + str[i + 1 :] #Remove char in i
        #explore
            permuteHelper(str,chosen) #Explore
        #unchoose
            str = str[:i] + currChar + str[i:] #Put currChar where it was
            chosen = chosen[:-1:] #Remove last char of chosen

permute("abc")
//
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
```

Which gave me the result I was looking for.

But when I tried to implement the same logic on array of integers:

```
def permute(nums):
    lst = []
    permuteHelper(nums, [], lst)

def permuteHelper(nums,chosen, lst):
    if len(nums) == 0:
        print(chosen)
        
    else:
        for i in range(len(nums)):
        #choose
            currNum = nums[i]
            chosen.append(currNum)
            nums.pop(i)
        #explore
            permuteHelper(nums,chosen,lst)
        #unchoose
            nums.insert(i,currNum)
            chosen = chosen[:-1]

permute([1,2,3])
//
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 2]
[1, 2, 2, 1, 3]
[1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1]
[1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1]
```

The result I was looking for is:

[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]

Why does permute for numbers won't act the same?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I´m just starting with python so I can't tell you why that doesn't work that way.

```py
chosen = chosen[:-1] #seems not to hand it over for the next loop
```

It works if you choose:

```py
chosen.pop()
```